# How to check if string tag contained text is being updated

Tags: android, xml, string

I am showing data of a `<string name="whatsnew"> </string>` in a textview and i have to show this textview only when the text inside this being changed.

for eg:

If previous state is:

```
<string name="whatsnew">Hi Stackoverflow Collegues </string>
```

If current state is this data is being updated as:

```
<string name="whatsnew">Hello Stackoverflow Collegues</string>
```

I have implemented a logic that i will retrieve the previous and current stringlength of

`<string name="whatsnew"> </string>`

containing text.But this logic has a loop hole if the updated text is of same length of previous string length.

Please help me with a better and efficient logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use hashCode() of your string to compare, for example:

```
int hash = "this is my string".hashCode();
```

or simply compare with another string:

```
boolean isSame = "first string".equalsIgnoreCase("second string");
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you just compare the strings and set it visible if they are different?

```
if(oldString != newString){
   view.setVisibility(VIEW.Visible");
}
```

Comment: Thnx bjorn i will impliment this logic..!!

Answer (score 0):

[getText()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html) method may help .. check if the same text is in the TextView of it changed 
just compare the whole text